# Unwanted white space around image inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display an image inside a `div` with `bootstrap` and there's an uncalled for white space around the image. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm not talking about the white background - it's intentional. I am talking about the fact the image doesn't stretch to the width of the `div`. This is the code I'm using:

```
<div align="center" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-3 whitebgdiv" style="border:0px solid red; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;">
    <a href='#{product.itemUrl}' target="_blank"><img src='#{product.thumbnailUrl}' style="border: 0px solid blue;" class="img-responsive productimg vertical-align2" /></a> <br/>                            
</div>
```

The relevant `css` classes:

```
.whitebgdiv {
   background-image:url('../resources/images/whitebg.jpg');
   border-radius: 2px;
   margin-left:0px;
}

.productimg {
   width: 6em;
   max-width: 180px;
}
```

I tried `display:block` and `display:inline` but they do nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Fiddle or it didn't happen.

Comment: is it because of this style that there is white space?
`style="border:0px solid red; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;`

Comment: You have added width the img tag please remove the width from the productimg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.productimg{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If the width of its container is defined, you don't need to set a max-width on the image either with this code.

Answer (score 1):

use width 100% and remove max-width.

```
.productimg { display:block; width: 100%; height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width to image the white space is due to `max-width`  to image tag. the container(div) with is higher then the image width so your getting white space between those